# I don't understand the usefulness of len() in this exercice

Tags: python

I've started learning python few days ago and I'm training myself on codewars. One of the exercises was to calculate how many times a given word appears in the sentences. I made it my way but in the correction, some people are doing it this way:

```py
import re
def sum_of_a_beach(beach):
    return len(re.findall('Sand|Water|Fish|Sun', beach, re.IGNORECASE))
```

I understand most of it but I don't understand why is `len()` used.

Comment: len() count the values on array or string.

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list of words that match. `len` gives the count of the matches

Comment: `findall` returns a sequence of results. `len` tells you how many there are.

Comment: ooh so it will count how times the words are in it right ? I thought it was like in C only to know the length of a string.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.findall('Sand|Water|Fish|Sun', beach, re.IGNORECASE)` finds all the occurrences of the words (no word boundary, that is...).

`len` just counts those occurrences.

Using `count` on `beach` would work too, but you'd have to lowercase and perform a loop. regex avoids to convert to lowercase, and the loop is done with `|`

If you test it with:

```
s = "The sand is touching the water, it's fishy"
```

You'll get 3 occurrences. Maybe it's not what you want. So while you're using regular expressions, maybe you want to add the "word only" feature:

```
def sum_of_a_beach(beach):
    return len(re.findall(r'\b(Sand|Water|Fish|Sun)\b', beach, re.IGNORECASE))
```

This will only match whole words thanks to `\b` word boundary delimiter

Comment: thank you for the answer. I thought len was exclusively reserved for string length like in C.

Comment: nope. `len` applies to all _sequences_. Collections where the length is known in advance. Dictionaries, tuples, lists, strings for instance